# Collapse Shiny Dashboard sidebar with large width

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to hide a shinydashboard sidebar with a large width. The issue is when I increase the width, the sidebar doesn't completely go off the screen.

Here's an example of the problem I am trying to fix;

```
## R Code ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(tags$head(includeCSS("www/custom.css")))
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

and the CSS file is

```
## CSS ##
.left-side, .main-sidebar {
   width: 50vw;
}
```

This is the sidebar uncollapsed:
[image: Uncollapsed sidebar]

and this is the sidebar collapsed:

[image: Collapsed sidebar]

as you can tell, it didn't hide :(. Are there any suggestions as to how I would go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

utilize the display property in ccss.

so instead of altering the width do display:none;
this will resize your other elements and move things accordingly.
Please reference this wc3 link for example:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

Comment: Adding ".sidebar-collapse .main-sidebar {display:none;}" fixed the problem. Thanks!